# regex for pow()

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

First of all I just want to say that I never understood so well the regular expressions patterns, but I'm progressing :)

I want to create a function for replacing the "^" char and left right matches with pow($1, $2). I manged to get to a point that is acceptable but the string that I receive from an API keeps getting bigger & bigger and now I'm stuck... it's like this:

```
$str = '(0+1*9^3+3)*(4+5)-(6/7)+(1+2)/(1+1)^((2/3)*3-1+(2/3))';
$str = preg_replace('/([0-9]+|\([0-9\+\-\*\/]+\)|[^\+\-\*\/]\([\S]+\))\^([0-9]+|\([0-9\+\-\*\/]+\)|[^\+\-\*\/]\([\S]+\))/', 'pow($1,$2)', $str);
echo $str;
```

This works ok to the given string but if i add 1 more "+(1+2)/(1+1)^((2/3)*3-1+(2/3))'" to the end it doesn't work right.

Basically i want preg_replace to find the first "()" from the left & the first "()" from the right of "^" char

Examples of how it should work (I'll only do for the left side of "^" but it can applies as well on the right side)

```
3+2^3-2 => 3+pow(2, 3)-2
3+(1+1)^3*2 => 3+pow((1+1), 3)*2
3+(1+1+(1+2))^3/2 => 3+pow((1+1+(1+2)), 3)/2
3+((3/3)+(2/2))^2-1 => 3+pow(((3/3)+(2/2)), 2)-1
(3+1)^3-1 => pow((3+1), 3)-1
```

etc...

Sort for all above is:
return as "$1" what is before "^":
1. if the first thing before "^" is int, return the number
2. if the first thing is ")" search for it's pair "(" and return everything inside them (something like '/(/([.*]))\^/')

I'm sorry for my english, I hope you understood... and I hope that someone can help me on this problem :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you need a parser. Infinitely nested expressions (as in parenthesis) cannot<sup>1</sup> be matched by regular expressions alone. Consider this:

```
(2 ^ (2 ^ (2 ^ (2 ^ (2 ^ (2 ^ (...)))))))
```

What regular expression will match that? You can approximate it, you can match N levels of that, but you can't do it all.

You *should* make a parser. If you don't want to, I understand, because it's a lot of work. You may be able to get a regex solution that is good enough for your purposes now. But it won't work forever, because regular expressions are not sufficiently advanced to solve this problem.

---

1. Perl (and Perl-compatible regular expressions) *can* do this, but they shouldn't. Once you start using those features of Perl's regexes it becomes unreadable. Also, they're not (theoretically speaking) *regular* expressions, but no one really cares about theory. :P